# Windows 8.1 PC: Title bar doesn't show up for apps

Tags: windows-8.1

When I use apps from the start menu, the title bar with the name, minimize and close options initially shows up. It slides up after a couple of seconds which is normal behavior. But when I move the cursor to the top right corner, the title bar doesn't show up, leaving me the option of pressing Alt-F4 to quit the app.

This problem did not initially exist when I installed Windows 8.1. I tried PC settings, Taskbar and Navigation options in the Control Panel to fix this but with little aid.

Maybe this is a part of a bigger problem, as when I move to the left bottom corner of the screen and move up, the open apps switcher doesn't show up either.

Comment: Have you installed any Start Menu replacements (Like Classic Start, Start8 or Startisback)?